# webRTC to setup signaling server

Tags: webrtc

how to setup a signaling server for webRTC when the system are connected in Local Area Network? Its mandatory that we must use STUN and TURN server for signaling?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Webrtc needs some kind of signalling system for initial negotiation.. like transferring `SDP`, `ICE-candidates`, sending and receiving `offers` etc... rest is done by peer-peer connection. For initial signalling you can use any technique like sending AJAX calls, using socket.io etc.

STUN and TURN servers are required for NAT traversal, NAT traversal is important because it is needed for determining the path between peers. You can use google provided STUN/TURN server address `stun:stun.l.google.com:19302` etc , or you can configure your own turn server by using [rfc-5766 turn server](http://code.google.com/p/rfc5766-turn-server/)

Comment: Google provides a STUN server, but the server at that address does not function as a TURN server. TURN is a fairly intensive protocol for a server to support; so far as I know, there are none publicly available for free use. Also, STUN is sufficient for 92% of cases, while TURN will handle the remaining 8%. If you're only using the service on your LAN, you may be able to get away with just using Google's public STUN.

Comment: @Mack Can I ask where you got the 92% and 8% figures from? I have been looking for this info for a while and would love to know the source. Cheers.

Comment: One is used to coordinate p2p connections and the other is a proxy fallback. 92% able to traverse NAT (Or whatever) and use p2p doesn't sound bad.

Comment: IMHO, OP already has an idea that STUN and TURN not obligatory in a LAN (that is why he asked if it is 'mandatory'). @Deep Pai gave the straight forward answer ("You will not require a STUN/TURN server...in the LAN") - an answer I believe is more concise and aptin this context than reiterating what STUN and TURN are

Answer (score 14):

To make WebRTC run on LAN, you will require to have a signaling server in that LAN. A signaling server is any web server that will allow your web clients to exchange the SDP offer/answer and ICE candidates that are generated by the WebRTC PeerConnection. This can be done using AJAX or WebSockets.

I have listed some [top sources for information about WebRTC](http://deeppai.com/2014/01/26/getting-started-with-webrtc/). Please go through some of the links on that page to better understand how the WebRTC signaling works.

You will **not require** a STUN/TURN server as your WebRTC clients (i.e. Web Browser) will be in the LAN and accessible to each other. FYI... STUN/TURN servers are not part of the signaling but part of the media leg and usually required for [NAT traversals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal) of media.

Comment: Very good explanation .. thank you .. i always thought that STUN/TURN are part of the signaling and that I must have them

Answer (score 0):

Making signalling server for WebRTC is quite easy.
I used PHP, MYSQL and AJAX to maintain signalling data.
Suppose A wants to call B.

Then A creates offer using createOffer method.  This method returns an offer object.
You have to transfer this offer object to user B,  This is a part of  signalling process.

Now create MYSQL database, having columns :
caller, callee, offer, answer, callerICE and calleeICE

Now offer created by A is stored in offer attribute with the help of AJAX call .

(Remember to use JSON.stringify the JS object before "POSTing" object to server.)

Now user B  scans this offer attribute created by caller A , again with the help of AJAX  call.

In this way , offer object created at user A can arrive at user B.

Now, user B responds to the offer by calling createAnswer method. This method returns answer object. This can again be stored in "answer" attribute of database.
Then the caller A scans this "answer" attribute created by callee B.
In this way, answer object created  by B can arrive at A.

To store iceCandidate object representing caller A, use "callerIce" attribute of MYSQL table. Note that, callee B is scanning "callerIce" to know the details of caller A.
In this way we can transfer the iceCandidate objects representing future peer.

After you complete transferring of iceCandidate object, the connectionState property holds "connected" indicating two peers are connected.

If any questions, let me know!

Cheers ! You can now share local media stream to the remote peer.