# webRTC to connect two browser

Tags: p2p, webrtc

For a long time I'm trying to connect the two browsers. I'm getting my voice, my own camera image only.How do I get the image and sound other browsers? The browsers connecting on the same network.

```
<body>  


<video id="localVideo" autoplay="true" muted="true" width="400px" height="400px" ></video>
<video id="remoteVideo"  autoplay="true" muted="true" width="400px" height="400px" ></video>

<div>
    <button id="callButton" onclick="call();" >Call</button>
    <button id="hangupButton" onclick="hangup();" disabled>Hang Up</button>
</div>

<script>
    // Definitions
    var localStream;
    var callButton = document.getElementById("callButton");
    var hangupButton = document.getElementById("hangupButton");

    var localVideo = document.getElementById("localVideo");
    var remoteVideo = document.getElementById("remoteVideo");
    var audioVideoConstraints = {audio: true, video: true};

    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
    window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

    window.RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
    window.RTCIceCandidate = window.mozRTCIceCandidate;


</script>


<script>
 // Functions


function getUserMediaSuccessCallback(stream) {
  window.stream = stream; // stream available to console
  localStream = stream;
  if (window.URL) {
    localVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
  } else {
    localVideo.src = stream;
  }
  callButton.disabled = false;



  if (window.stream.getVideoTracks().length > 0) {
    trace('Using video device: ' + window.stream.getVideoTracks()[0].label);
  }
  if (window.stream.getAudioTracks().length > 0) {
    trace('Using audio device: ' + window.stream.getAudioTracks()[0].label);
  }

}

function getUserMediaErrorCallback(error){
  console.log("navigator.getUserMedia error: ", error);
  alert("navigator.getUserMedia error: " + error);
}

function trace(text) {
  console.log(text);
}

function call() {

  hangupButton.disabled = false;
  trace("Starting call");

  var servers = null;

  localPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
  trace("Created local peer connection object localPeerConnection");
  localPeerConnection.onicecandidate = gotLocalIceCandidate;

  remotePeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
  trace("Created remote peer connection object remotePeerConnection");
  remotePeerConnection.onicecandidate = gotRemoteIceCandidate;
  remotePeerConnection.onaddstream = gotRemoteStream;

  localPeerConnection.addStream(localStream);
  trace("Added localStream to localPeerConnection");
  localPeerConnection.createOffer(gotLocalDescription);
}




</script>


<script>

    navigator.getUserMedia(audioVideoConstraints, getUserMediaSuccessCallback, getUserMediaErrorCallback);
```

Thank you very much good work :)

Comment: what are you using for your signalling server? You even need one on the local network(no ICE server is needed however). This [SO question may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21354278/webrtc-to-setup-signaling-server). Also, you have two connection objects in the same page. You do not need that. HTML is stateless and if two people go to the "same page" it is not the exact same page and the scripts that are executed will be unique to that page.

Comment: Hello @Oğuzhan Başkaya and welcome on SO ! http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics is a good place to start

Comment: Thanks nha i readed this article. But my problem is not solved. I can call and i can see myself on two part. I need to connect to other computers on the same network. Video from the browser need to talk to other computers. I send a request, then answer the request and need to establish a connection. But how? I readed the websocket. Need to integrate with my code...